# Twitter Tweet or TwitterMeme button?

Tags: twitter

The [Twitter Tweet button](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button) and the [Tweetmeme Retweet button](http://tweetmeme.com/about/retweet_button) seem to pretty much do the exact same thing.

Which should I use and why?

-- It seems that Tweetmeme is now recommending the Twitter Tweet button. But I still see lots and lots of Tweetmeme buttons around the 'net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the official one.
[Twitter took over the basic button](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/12/twitter-tweet-button/) last year, anyway. Any actual Tweetmeme buttons you *still* see were most likely just never updated/switched and there'd eventually just be a redirect of some kind on their end that leads to essentially the same result.